# Programmatically Modify EditForm.aspx

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am working with document upload, after upload, it takes user to EditForm.aspx, where I do not want few of the fields displayed.

How do I hide Fields from EditForm.aspx programmatically? Including automated deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

You simply update the list fields to set them as non editable via the ShowInEditForm property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.showineditform.aspx

Comment: Thanks for reply. How about ContentType field. Which is a predefined field shown when uploading a document to document library. How do I get rid of that field?

Comment: When you add items to a document library you have to associate them with a content type. The content type defines the fields available for that particular document type.(well it is alot more but for your case that should be all you need to know)

Comment: Thanks Brian.... Got it. I don't see ShowInEditForm property with ContentTypes. Though I can see Hidden, I haven't tested yet, but I believe should do the job.